# Stop Multiple Processes In PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Firstly I will stress I am new to powershell.

I am trying to stop all instances of two processes ,  I have written and run the below in powershell, but it is actually giving me a BSOD, so I must have done something fairly stupid.

Can anyone point out where I have gone wrong ?

```
   $processes = Get-Process 
   foreach ($process in $processes)
   {
   if($process.ProcessName -eq "chrome" -or "chromedriver")
   {
      $process | Stop-Process -Force
   }

 }
```

Comment: arco444 beat me to it, but if you `echo` what you're `Stop-Process`ing, or add a `-confirm` tag to `Stop-Process` you would see it. Liberal use of print statements is key to learning a new language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
if(($process.ProcessName -eq "chrome") -or ($process.ProcessName -eq "chromedriver"))
{
    $process | Stop-Process -Force
}
```

Otherwise you're saying `if(some_condition -or true)`, the results of which will always evaluate to true, so you go through your list killing all processes!

A string is not a null value so PowerShell will interpret it as true. You can test in the console by:

```
[PS] > $null -or $null
False
[PS] > $null -or "abc"
True
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic concerning the `if` statements as Arco444 explains is correct. Conditions are evaluated independently and a non-null non-empty string evaluates as true with cast as `[bool]`

```
[bool]"chromedriver"
```

Another way to deal with this could be to use `-contains`. If you have several things you are checking against for one value.

```
If("chrome","chromedriver" -contains $process.ProcessName){
    $process | Stop-Process -Force
}
```

Better yet would be to filter the processes you are returning since you are only looking for certain ones anyway. For the cmdlets that support it `-WhatIf` can also be helpful for debugging.

```
Get-Process "chrome","chromedriver" | Stop-Process -Force -WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to PowerShell but try this:

```
get-process | where-object { $_.Name -eq "chrome" -or $_.Name -eq "chromedriver" } | stop-process -force
```

I tried it with stop-process `-WhatIf` and it looks good on mine. I'm using the PowerShell ISE in Windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Process chromedriver | Stop-Process -Force
```

That did it for me...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still needs this Example:
Windows 11 , Powershell v5.1

```
Stop-Process -processname "chrome","cmd","firefox","msedge" -force
```